# Is there any difference if I use link relation tag (rel=next etc) at the end of URL?

Tags: html

I want to add the rel=next to next link and rel=prev to the previous link on my blog's homepage. But I am wondering is there any difference if we place these link relation tags at the end of URL, like this

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/page/2/" rel="next"> Next</a>
```

These days I find most developers put the link relation tag at the start of the URL. Example;

```
<a rel="next" href="http://www.example.com/page/2/"> Next</a>
```

Is there any difference between these two approaches??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can order different HTML attributes in any way you like and it won't change anything.

Comment: And won't there be any effect on SEO (esp related to pagination)?? I have been reading recently that Google uses relation tags to reduce duplicate content etc.

Comment: I said it won't change anything. Google doesn't really care if you put the `rel` attribute first or last. In fact... I doubt it even takes `rel` attributes seriously anymore.

Comment: @BoltClock - Someone recently pointed me to http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html, which indicates that Google does make use of the prev and next rel values.

Comment: @Alohci You are right. Google may consider these tags to deliver the best results.